# use .val to get value of fields with same names

Tags: jquery

I have an address field named "addressarr[]". Users can have multiple fields of the address.

I want to know if it's possible for me to check if all addressarr[] fields are filled up.

This is my code that checks the fields.

```
 function check() {
    var cn = document.getElementById('clientname').value;
    var e = document.getElementById("clienttype");
    var ct = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var cp= $ ("[name=addressarr").val();

    //var cp = document.getElementById('contactperson').value;
    //var cu = document.getElementById('contactnumber').value;
    if (cn == "") {
        document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = 'Please enter full name';
        $('#modalerror').modal('show');
    }else if (ct == "Select Client Type") {
        document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = 'Please pick client type';
        $('#modalerror').modal('show');
    }else if (cp == "") {
        document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = 'Please enter address';
        $('#modalerror').modal('show');
    }
```

This is my HTML file.

```
                          <div class= "form-group" id= "diva">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Address</label>    
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                             <p><input type=text class="form-control" rows="2" name="addressarr[]" id="addressarr[]" size="20" maxlength="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['addressarr']) && !$flag) echo $_POST['addressarr'][0]; ?>"/></p>
                        </div>
                          <input type="button" name="addaddress" class=" btn btn-default" id="adda" value="Add Address"/>
                      </div>
```

This is my code that appends when user wants to have multiple fields.

```
              $("#adda").click(function() {

              $("#diva").append('<p><div class="row" id= newp><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><label class="col-sm-1 control-label"></label><div class="col-sm-5 ">  <input type=text class="form-control" rows="2" name="addressarr[]" id="addressarr[]" size="20 maxlength="45" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['addressarr']) && !$flag) echo $_POST['addressarr'][0]; ?>" />  </div> <input type="button" name="removeadd" class=" btn btn-danger" id="rema" value="Remove"/></div></div></p');   
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to select elements based on any criterion. In your case, something like this should do it:

```
var empties = $('input[name="addressarr[]"]').filter(
  function(){
    return $(this).val() == '';
  });
if(empties.length > 0){
    alert('empty fields'); //do whatever you need to do here
}
```